# Unable to run awk program

Tags: awk

I have created a simple awk program file in `/media/ravan/data/program`

The code:

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { print "Don’t Panic bro!" }
```

While executing in terminal:

```
ravan@ravan:/media/ravan/data/program$ ls
awkTest.awk  testawk.awk
ravan@ravan:/media/ravan/data/program$ chmod +x awkTest.awk
ravan@ravan:/media/ravan/data/program$ ./awkTest.awk
bash: ./awkTest.awk: Permission denied
```

The part of `mount` output

```
/dev/sda3 on /media/ravan/data type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
```

The output of `ls -l`

```
ravan@ravan:~$ ls -l /media/ravan/data/program
total 1
-rw------- 1 ravan ravan 55 Nov  9 15:03 awkTest.awk
-rw------- 1 ravan ravan 52 Nov  9 13:29 testawk.awk
```

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/11840/158442

Comment: as you are doing it from non root partition , you should use sh . so ` sh awkTest.awk`

Comment: @Raja, this a an awk script, not shell.

Comment: OK Glenn I will wait for answer then...thanks glenn

Comment: I think you have to change your mount options: change **default_permissions**  to **permissions** so chmod will work

Comment: Maybe just `. awkTest.awk`. Using the 'dot' which is a synonim of `source`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's going on with your filesystem mount, but working around it is very simple.  You just need to understand what the shebang is actually doing.

When a file is marked executable and you try to run it, the first two bytes of the file are checked.  If they are `#!`, then the shell will run that first line of your file as a command, followed by the path to the file itself as an argument to that command.

In other words, `#!/bin/bash`, placed as the first line in a file called `/tmp/myscript.sh`, will be run as `/bin/bash /tmp/myscript.sh`.

Likewise, `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` as the first line of `./awkTest.awk`, when run, becomes (or should become if your mount issue weren't interfering) `/usr/bin/awk -f ./awkTest.awk`.

The solution is to just run `awk -f awkTest.awk` and your script will run as expected.

---

Note that since `awk` is *interpreted* rather than compiled, a `noexec` flag on the mount options of the device that holds your awk script *won't* prevent you from running your script.  It only prevents you from running it *as an executable*.  So all you need to do is run your `awk` binary executable (`/usr/bin/awk`) and it will *read* your `awk` script, which is of course not prevented by the `noexec` flag, and it will do what you scripted.

Comment: thanks for reply, I report you back, once I reached home. :)